# Efficient way of removing multi entries from Java Properties Object

Tags: java, properties

I have a `Properties` object with approximately 10k elements in it. And I want to remove entries(key/value) that their key start with a specific text. Currently, I am using this code to do so:

```
Properties temp = new Properties();
myProperties.keySet().forEach(key -> {
    if (!key.toString().startsWith("specificText")){
        temp.setProperty(key, myProperties.get(key));
    }
});
myProperties = temp;
```

Another solution is using putAll instead of calling setProperty multiple times:

```
Properties temp = new Properties();
temp.putAll(myProperties.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> !entry.getKey().toString().startsWith("specificText")     
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
myProperties= temp;
```

But none of the above solutions are efficient enough for my work. I am sure there should be a better way to remove unwanted properties. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your two solutions don't remove any property. They create a filtered copy of the original. Is that what you want, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a Map’s keySet directly affects the Map itself:

```
myProperties.keySet().removeIf(key -> key.toString().startsWith("specificText"));
```

From the [documentation of Map.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--):

> The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map…

Comment: I knew there was a simple solution for it. Thanks a lot ;)